# How to add two numbers from string

Tags: php, string

```
$str ='824+6';
```

With `$strpos($str,"+");` I can get where the `+` is. I want to get at the end the result of `824+6`.

Comment: Can you be clear on what `at the end the result` mean

Comment: The actual question here is how to extract the numbers. Adding them together is not the problem.

Comment: If the string is not user input, you can safely use `eval()`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have just a `+` in there, the following should work.

```
$parts = explode( '+', $str );
$sum = $parts[0] + $parts[1];
```

- [PHP docu for `explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$parts = explode( '+', $str );
$sum = intval($parts[0]) + intval($parts[1]);

Need to convert string to number and then add those.
```

--
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. The second is the concatenating assignment operator ('.='), which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side. Please read Assignment Operators for more information.

```
 <?php
$a = "Hello ";
$b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"

$a = "Hello ";
$a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$var = explode("+", "123+100");
echo $var[0]+$var[1];
```